# Q: R NNETAR external regressors incorporation

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

This is a question about the statistical intuition of the nnetar function of the forecast package. To my knowledge, little is mentioned in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)
 and the actual manual of the forecast package. If there are other

I understand that nnetar leverages the nnet library. What I do not understand is how the external regressors "xreg" are factored into the hidden layer.

In other words, as professor Hyndman suggests in [the arimax model muddle](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), the auto.arima function fits the ARIMA part based on the specified test and the unit roots and the "X" external regressors are factored in through the xreg argument. If there are multiple external regressors, the end result is a multiple linear regression with ARIMA errors.

What is the equivalent for nnetar? Are there coefficients for those external variables? How are the contributions of the external variables factored in and how would I find their relative weight?

Finally, I am aware of the bsts package which is, to me, even more opaque. Are there other similar packages for such non-parametric forecasting?

Answer (score 1):

External regressors are just added as additional covariates together with the lagged values of the response (like the first equation in the ["ARMAX models" section](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)). This is in contrast to a regression model with ARMA errors.

The weights *can* be retrieved, but I'm not sure how helpful they'll be. There are several complicating factors:

- It's hard to derive meaning from neural network weights in general
- In `nnetar` the external regressors are fitted jointly with the lagged values (as I mentioned above)
- Unless otherwise specified, `nnetar` fits multiple networks (20 by default) with different random starting weights and then averages their forecasts.

In case you do want to see them, here's a simple example to get the weights from each network:

```
library(forecast)
mynnetar <- nnetar(lynx)
mynnetar$model[[1]]$wts
mynnetar$model[[2]]$wts
## ...
mynnetar$model[[20]]$wts
```

This returns a vector of the weights for each network. I believe it's ordered as inputs-hidden-output, but you'll have to look at the `nnet` documentation to confirm that, and to check which correspond to the bias. The external regressors are placed after the lagged values in the model matrix.

The [CRAN Task View for time series](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) lists many packages for forecasting and may have others that are useful for you.

Comment: I wish there were examples of usage of xreg in nnetar.